# Is is possible to copy files over the network using an software installer?

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, file-transfer

Basically, I need a software installer to overwrite files which reside on a few PCs that are in the same network. Example: I have PC A. I run this installer and it will copy and overwrite files to some folders in PC B, C, D, and E. Is there a installer available in the market that can do that?

By the way, one of the system runs Linux while others run Windows 7.

Comment: on a domain? its all about permissions and if you have access/rights to those files....

Comment: Scripts (nowadays powershell on Windows) are used for this type of work. Can you detail *why* it has to be an 'installer' if it's only running on machine A? The other computers won't know the difference.